# Relink mySQL database in an access file

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

I have an access file that's servers as a front end to a mySQL database. In the access file I have a couple of tables and queries made. The problem is I changed the mySQL database from one host to another, and the other one doesn't exist.

What I want to do it's relink the tables/queries in this access file to the database rather than the old database. I deleted the old ODBC record I had on my computer, and created the new one. But what happens it's that each time I try to access one of the queries it brings up the ODBC connection properties and I must change the connection hostname from my old one, to the new one. I believe the old information is stored somewhere in the file, so any information regarding where this is stored or whenever I have to manually do it by VBA code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible places for the information to be stored:

1. in the connect strings for linked tables.
2. in the connect strings for saved queries.

You can find out the connect string for a table with this:

```
  ?CurrentDB.TableDefs("MyTable").Connect
```

...and for a saved query with:

```
  ?CurrentDB.QueryDefs("MyQuery").Connect
```

For updating the former, you should just delete the existing linked tables and relink from scratch. For the latter, you'll have to edit each individually, or write code to go through the QueryDefs collection and alter and save the Connect strings with the new value.

You may also find [Doug Steele's code for DSN-less connect strings](http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html) useful.

Comment: My doubt here is how do I start writing the code. Can you please provide step by step instructions on how should I write it. (Not the code for linking it itself, but rather where. IE. Go to X part of the Access Database, write a function called X, and then you can set it up to automatically run like this)

Comment: Well, you don't actually have to write any code -- you could do it manually. The first thing to do is to determine where the connect strings are. If they are in the linked tables, then do as I said, and delete the existing links and use the linked table manager to recreate them (no code!). If, on the other hand, the connect strings are in the queries, you might want to check how many -- if it's only one or two, then there's not much point in writing code to fix it.